# Bad Request using OAuth (with Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

[image]

I get this error when I use `require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy` instead of `require('passport-google-oauth20')`, without the `.strategy`.

Either way, I facing the problem where "Passport callback function fired" but I get that error message and my `new User()` never runs! Can someone advise? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I use it without the ".Strategy", everything else is same as ur code, works like a charm for me. Oso take note if you use heroku, you need to set an extra option in GoogleStrategy. Under client ID option, put `proxy: "true"`

Comment: @hoohoo-b Hey there. Do you have a github repo you could share with me so that I can check? I still face the same problem without the `.strategy`

Comment: Here you go! [Github repo](https://github.com/mshankr/gdykuku)